# user enters String instead of Int

Tags: c++

We have tried to search this problem but we haven't found any answers. If The user inputs a string variable when the system requires a integer how do you evade the problem with out using a while loop?

```
{

    int grade_var=0,grade_1=0,sum=0;

    cout<<"Enter the number of grades you have:\t";


    cin>>grade_var;


    for(int i=1;i<=grade_var;i++)
```

I don't wish to do a while loop for my program has a lot of integer insertions and want to know an easier way to correct rather than while loops?

Comment: exactly how will you "go back" to the 'get input' code if bad data is entered, WITHOUT a loop? You could simply nest `if (input is bad) { get more input { if (input is bad) { .... }}` as deeply as you want. but if you check `n` times for bad inputs, someone WILL enter bad stuff `n+1` times and bypass your checking. A loop is far simpler. `while (input is bad) { get input }` is

Comment: @MarcB: more appropriate, `do { ask input } while(input is bad)`.

Comment: The only solution that doesn't involve loops I can think of is placing your input in helper function and use recursion: `if(inputisbad) readinput()`

Answer (score 2):

While loops are generally the way to go.

However, to keep the code clean, you may want to consider putting said while loop into a helper function, so you can just call PollForIntegerInput(string prompt) from anywhere in your code, and then handle that input in one place. There is almost never a reason you should be duplicating an input loop like that.

As for a truly nonlooping answer, I have none.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `operator>>` on a stream returns the stream itself, which can be converted to `bool` to check if the stream is in a good state. If a bad extraction happens, the stream is not in a good state. So you can do something like this:

```
if (cin >> grade_var)
```

This will check that it was successful. You can just negate the condition to find it if it wasn't successful. How you handle this condition is up to. Maybe you'll `return` early on failure. If you want to reprompt the user for correct input, however, you'll need a loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too clear what your problem is, but...

It's almost always poor design to input the number of data
points which will follow.  If you expect a series of `int`, for
example:

```
std::vector<int> grades;
int grade;
while ( std::cin >> grade ) {
    grades.push_back( grade );
}
```

It doesn't get much simpler.

If you do want to insist on an exact number of input, outputting
an error when the user inputs something incorrect, the usual
pattern would be:

```
std::vector<int> grades;
while ( grades.size() != targetNumber ) {
    int grade;
    while ( !(std::cin >> grade) ) {
        std::cout << "Integer wanted" << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore( INT_MAX, '\n' );
    }
    grades.push_back( grade );
}
```

Still no `for`.  (In fact, `for` loops with input are very, very
rare.)