# Console is being flooded when error checking for things that are not an int

Tags: c++, integer, error-checking

I'm trying to only allow integer values into my program, so I've made the following function. The function is similar to other ones I've seen online, and mine seems to work just fine up until I add an ! in front of it to check if something is not an int.

Function to check if input is an integer:

```
bool isInteger(std::string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(s[i]) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Function being put to use:

```
int getLevel()
{
    int level;

    std::cout << "Level One\n";
    std::cout << "Level Two\n";
    std::cout << "Level Three\n";
    std::cout << "Level Four\n";
    std::cout << "Level Five\n";
    std::cout << "Enter your level (1-5): ";
    std::cin >> level;

    while (!isInteger(std::to_string(level)) || level < 1 || level > 5)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter an integer value between 1-5 inclusive: ";
        std::cin >> level;
    }

    clrscr();
    return level;;
}
```

I believe the function works just fine until I put the ! in front of it. I am trying to only allow integer input into my program, and when I enter a double or string, the console becomes flooded with the message "Enter an integer value between 1-5 inclusive: " and doesn't give any time to enter an input. I am fairly new to c++ programming and could use some advice. Thank you!

Comment: If you read a string into an integer, this will simply fail, and then `level` is still uninitialized. Then converting it to a string (or using it in any way), is not allowed.

Comment: Additionally I would check first the length of the user input being 1 character, unless you want to allow "0005"

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cin >> level;
```

will try to read an integer and it will never read anything other than an integer. If this fails `std::cin`'s `failbit` is set and further input operations (like `std::cin >> level;` inside the loop) are skipped.

You need to check if the reading succeeded and ignore the current input if not. Like this for example:

```
std::cout << "Enter your level (1-5): ";

while(!(std::cin >> level) || level < 1 || level > 5) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    std::cout << "Enter an integer value between 1-5 inclusive: ";
}
```

---

As little semi-related hint: `level` will *always* be an integer. Converting it to a string will *always* be the string-representation of an integer, so `isInteger(std::to_string(level))` will *always* be `true`, unless `level` is negative, because you don't check for the sign.

Also that `return true;` in `isInteger` must be outside the loop, else you only check the first character.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the replies and clarification, I've managed to come up with a solution of my own.

New isInteger function that now checks for everything that is needed including inputs like "0004" that a user suggested above:

```
bool errorCheck(std::string s)
{
    int intLevel;
    std::stringstream tempLvl(s);
    tempLvl >> intLevel;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(s[i]) == false || s[0] == '0' || intLevel < 1 || intLevel > 5)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The method in action:

```
    std::cout << "Enter your level (1-5): ";
    std::cin >> stringLevel;

    while (!errorCheck(stringLevel))
    {
        std::cout << "Enter an integer value between 1-5 inclusive: ";
        std::cin >> stringLevel;
    }

    std::stringstream lvl(stringLevel);
    lvl >> level;

    clrscr();
    return level;
}
```

Please let me know if you spot any problems with the code or have any easier solutions. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You overcomplicate things quite much. In `errorCheck` when `tempLvl >> intLevel;` succeeds you don't have to check if every character of the string is a digit. If it fails reading from `intLevel` can cause undefined behaviour (up until C++20, I think), because of reading an unitilized variable. `if( tempLvl >> intLevel) is so much easier. ``s[0] == '0' || intLevel < 1 || intLevel > 5` can be moved outside the loop at least.

Answer (score 0):

ok i am gonna tell u the fact that console input extracts the input from console so if u ever tried to do something like that 
i.e read string in place of integer the `cin` is going to be in bad state you can check this fact by putting an `if` like this

```
if(!cin>>level) break;
```

and u will find it working actually stream takes input from the console and convert it to `boolean` value so u can always check it's state bad state return `false` else `true`...... ..

SO,finally the bug is in `cin>>level`... 
I hope u understood.... also check out that `return true` statement..

i am gonna put u reference link for more answer on this bug...
[user enters String instead of Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745771/user-enters-string-instead-of-int)